# Do Heidegger and some of his readers know why there is something rather than nothing?

Tags: existence, heidegger

Do Heidegger and some of his readers know why there is something rather than nothing? There seems to the suggestion in the [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness) that he may explain why, but it's unclear in what way the argument can be rewritten, and surely (I'm thinking) if it's propositional knowledge it can be rewritten by someone, and understood, even if the explanation is very lengthy indeed.

Can we answer "that's the meaning of Being" and shift the question back to "what is the meaning of Being", or is that an inadequate gloss of his work?

Comment: and rewritten not by saying 'Being' or referring back to the text to paraphrase every movement it makes haha

Comment: ## Why is there *some*thing rather than *no*thing? ## Because *nothingness* is *not* **real**. Literally isn't real. So if it isn't real, then it's an *abstract concept*. Whereas 'something' (*matter*) is real, therefore unlike nothingness it exists (is).

Comment: The first step would probably be to read Heidegger's "What is Metaphysics?"

Comment: i have, just not recently @transitionsynthesis

Comment: My answer shouldn't have been converted to a comment, because it is the only rational answer to the question. Sometimes the simplest answers are the best answers. It had been upvoted, too.

Comment: @Bread i didn't downvote (or, obviously, convert). that nothingness does not exist need not mean that nothingness ***could not*** have exitsed?

Comment: although it *may* seem that way. thanks for the comment! @Bread

Comment: Heidegger ended up endorsing the Zen view as expounded by Dr. Suzuki. so would share the view of Nagarjuna and 'non-dualism' on Something and Nothing. This view denies a metaphysical or fundamental distinction between Something and Nothing.

Comment: we seem to have established that some of his readers think he knows it. less of a consensus on why... e.g. @PeterJ

Answer (score 1):

### Why is there *some*thing rather than *no*thing?

Because *nothingness* is *not* **real**. Literally isn't real.

So if it isn't real, then it's an *abstract concept*.

Whereas 'something' (*matter*) is real, therefore unlike nothingness it exists (is).

**________________________________________________________**

It should be obvious by now, that I consider Heidegger's remarks on the subject of "nothingness" to be meaningless, confusing nonsense. I think my explanation is much more logical. And Louis Kattsoff, in his book *Logic and the Nature of Reality* (1967) presents a rational explanation that is very similar but even simpler than mine:

> The key lies in the word *become*. In a sense this is unfortunate because it throws us against one of the very difficult problems in philosophy -- the meaning of the word 'becomes' or the nature of becoming. This is a problem that philosophers from Thales to Whitehead have found full of riddles that seemed to defy solution. Reflection may indicate that the word 'become' is not quite appropriate here, at least in one of its senses. Contrast the expression, "a child becomes a man" with "what was ***not***...comes to **be**."

The former expresses a continuous, flowing *process* involving a chain of causes and effects; whereas the latter only expresses an effect *for which there can be no cause*.

> But it is [impossible] to say that what was **not** [i.e. nothing or nothingness] comes to be what **is**, in the same way. [Nothingness] cannot be said to be remolded or to evolve into anything.
>
> ### This appears...to be true even if we create by the capitalization of nothing into Nothing a **quasi-substance** Nothing.

In other words, even if we imagine that Nothingness is something.

Comment: off topic, but i thought you might like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80EnupogigM)

Comment: That's wild old video, :D Btw, I am an occasional "reader" of Heiddeger, and I respect his work. I plan (later today) to add some philosophical reference(s) here, to back up my reasoning. I've already found one with which Heiddeger may or may not have agreed; nevertheless, with a little luck I might be able to establish some link to him for you.

Comment: ya fashions change, i just liked the phrase "is he in hell, nobody can tell"

Comment: Whither shall I go from thy spirit? or whither shall I flee from thy presence? If I ascend up into heaven, thou art there: if I make my bed in hell, behold, thou art there...If I say, Surely the darkness shall cover me; even the night shall be light about me. Yea, the darkness hides not from thee; but the night shines as the day: the darkness and the light are both alike to thee...I will praise thee; for I am fearfully and wonderfully made: marvelous are thy works; and that, my soul knows right well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this toy model. Flip a coin an  infinite number of times (it's a toy model, so anything is possible).

Define **nothing** as completely random , no correlation,  no simple rule to generate the sequence of heads/tails, **nothing** that makes sense

Define **something** as non random, for example  an infinite sequence of heads would be uncharacteristic , and many others.

Due to our limited human ability to process only finite amounts of information,  we can realistically talk only about finite sequences of results within our toy model, and for any finite sequence, we can find a structural, constructing, explanatory rule that would generate it. That's **something**, isn't  it , surely it's not **nothing**, according to our definitions.

A somehow similar situation appears in physics, the Wheeler - DeWitt equation (in quantum gravity) is timeless. The reemergence of time needs decoherence , and is related only to limited subsystems of the whole system.

Anyway, going back to our toy model, our perception of **something** , rather than **nothing** is a consequence of our limited ability to process only finite amounts of information , in finite time.

Just a thought.

Comment: It would seem that our limited ability comes prior to this something or nothing that we perceive. It would be a something so then why does that ability exists?

Comment: We have to define " something " and " nothing" in term of our categories of thought and  perception of the world around us, otherwise we cannot answer the question.  My point is that the distinction between " something " and " nothing " is a " stubbornly persistent illusion " , to paraphrase Einstein when referring to our perception of time.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I have to oppose any pre-scientific perspective on this matter, so in fact I do not follow Heidegger here, you're right, I do not answer the exact question asked. I'm trying to answer a question  that has an answer regardless of whether us, humans, exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

The New Ontological Proof

Here is why there is Something and not Nothing. Consider. Possibilities necessarily exist, do they not? Even if there were nothing and not something, something would still be a possibility, would it not? Therefore possibilities necessarily exist. Getting a bit away from Heidegger (whom I don't think really does answer the question, at least not ontologically) and taking a page (actually several) from David Lewis's "On the Plurality of Worlds". Possible worlds in fact exist, though my only quibble with this is as follows. Possibilities come into "full" existence only when they are chosen (because they continually and infinitely branch) and are thereby "realized". It is this whole process of realizing possibilities that we call "time". (And Heidegger did call his magnum opus "Being and Time", closely relating the two.) But in any case, Q.E.D.

Comment: nice idea, but a bit special / unique

Comment: "It's so special." -- Dana Carvey's "Church Lady"